# find_by_ dynamic finder stopped to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a really strange behaviour. My Rails 3 models do not provide me with the dynamic finder methods anymore. If I call a method, e.g. Person.find_by_lastname("Smith") I get a nil object back. When I try to autocomplete-tab the model's find_by methods, I only get 'find', 'find_by_sql', 'find_each' and 'find_in_batches'.

Another strange thing is, that if I call any method on a model, I get nil back, even if the method does not exist in the model.
Models can be saved and taken from the database as usual.

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you modified `method_missing` anywhere?

Comment: No, there is no definition of method_missing in my project.

Comment: Sounds like you may have a gem that has.  I'd start pulling the gems out one by one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I used the Gemfile from a previous release and checked it into the current release. That solved the problem.

Comment: any idea which gem was the offender?

Comment: It was the gem 'annotate' which I had in a very old version...